# Complex varieties which are not homotopic in complex-analytic topology but have the same etale homotopy types

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Do there exist smooth quasi-projective complex varieties $X_1$, $X_2$ such that $X_1(\mathbb{C})$ is not homotopy equivalent to $X_2(\mathbb{C})$ but their etale homotopy types coincide?

Comment: There are famous examples of this described by Serre.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201875/nonabelian-topological-fundamental-group-of-a-conjugate-variety