# Serre's examples in rigid analytic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, rigid-analytic-geometry

Over $\mathbb{C}$, we have the following phenomenon: there exist algebraic varieties whose etale homotopy types are isomorphic but the homotopy types of their analytifications are not. Such examples were [given](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201875/nonabelian-topological-fundamental-group-of-a-conjugate-variety#comment501437_201875) by Serre, among others. At least for smooth projective varieties, I think the etale homotopy type is the profinite completion of the homotopy type of the analytification, so this kind of illustrates that algebraic geometry sees only "finite things".

For algebraic varieties defined over a $p$-adic field, we can consider rigid analytification (this may be ambiguous because there are several versions I think, probably should not matter too much).

First question: what is some reasonable way to define the homotopy type of rigid analytic spaces so that it captures non-profinite information? Second question: does the phenomenon mentioned above occur in this setting?

Comment: Two possible notions of coverings of rigid spaces are de Jong's étale coverings (http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1995__97_1-2_89_0/) and André's tempered coverings (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.msjm/1389986016).  In both cases, the fundamental group is generally different from the fundamental group determined by finite étale coverings.